# Spring security guest user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom `UserDetails` implementation that has a shopping cart property.

```
class MyUserDetails implement UserDetails {
    private Cart cart;
    // getters & setters + other properties....
}
```

I want anonymous users to be a instance of MyUserDetails too, so far I have gotten it working otherwise, but all anonymousUsers have the same shopping cart!

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    MyUserDetails anonymousUser = new MyUserDetails();
    anonymousUser.setUsername("anonymousUser");
    http.anonymous().principal(anonymousUser);
    ...
}
```

How would I be able to return a new instance of MyUserDetails for anonymous users **for each session?**

Comment: I would say the write way is to have the shopping cart in your session. Your authentication doesn't need the shopping cart. `UserDetails` should only contain core user informations.

Comment: @dur I think the shopping cart could belong to the user. If I for example, want for a registered users shopping cart to persist between logins, or between different devices.

Comment: Sure it is part of the user, but it doesn't mean that it should be part of `UserDetails`. You can put the shopping cart in your session or load it from database. That has nothing to do with `UserDetails`.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I managed to get it working by creating a custom `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` like this:

```
public class MyAnonymousAuthenticationFilter extends AnonymousAuthenticationFilter {
    private static final String USER_SESSION_KEY = "user";
    private final String key;

    public MyAnonymousAuthenticationFilter(String key) {
        super(key);
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    protected Authentication createAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req) {
        HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession();
        MyUserDetails user = Optional.ofNullable((MyUserDetails) httpSession.getAttribute(USER_SESSION_KEY))
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    MyUserDetails anon = new MyUserDetails();
                    anon.setUsername("anonymousUser");
                    httpSession.setAttribute(USER_SESSION_KEY, anon);
                    return anon;
                });
        return new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(key, user, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ANONYMOUS"));
    }
}
```

and then use it with `http.anonymous().authenticationFilter(new MyAnonymousAuthenticationFilter(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));`

If there is something wrong with this approach, or if you know a better way, please let me know!

Comment: Is the user always going to be anonymous? or for specific url patterns?

Answer (score 1):

My first remark is that I tend to agree with the comments of @dur but that's another story :-)

If you still prefer to stick to your approach then I think it would be more inline with Spring architecture if instead of a filter you 
Implement your own [AuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html) which is able to process (authenticate) anonymous tokens. Like this:

```
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    //enrich the authentication here.
  }


  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return (AnonymousAuthenticationToken.class
        .isAssignableFrom(authentication));
  }
}
```

You will then register this provider in your filter chain which might be initialized by a [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html), for example. You will do this by configuring the local authentication manager. This will look somehow like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(new MyAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

For an excellent in-depth review of the spring security architecture please see [here](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/).